# What is the simplest way to split two lists in Python?

Tags: python

What is the simplest way to split two lists in Python?

```
var = [['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow']]

mylist =  [['item1'],['item2'], var]
```

Output:

```
mylist = [['item1','item2'], [['apple', 'banana'], ['red','yellow']]]
```

I need:

```
mylist = [['item1','item2'], ['apple', 'banana'], ['red','yellow']]
```

How can I split my list correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is *extend* the list by the values in `var`. So you can just use `+` to add the two lists together.

```
>>> var = [['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow']]
>>> mylist =  [['item1'], ['item2']] + var
>>> mylist
[['item1'], ['item2'], ['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow']]
```

Otherwise, if you have `[item, anotherList]`, you are essentially *embedding* the whole `anotherList` as a *single element* inside the new list. So you add another list level.

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [['item1','item2']] + var
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use extend method of list:

as:

```
        var = [['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow']]
        mylist =  [['item1'],['item2']]
        mylist.extend(var)
        print mylist

        Result: [['item1'], ['item2'], ['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow']]
```

Which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:
var = [['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow']]
mylist =  [['item1'],['item2'], var]

```
INSTEAD OF mylist =  [['item1'],['item2'], var]
use:
var = [['apple', 'banana'], ['red', 'yellow'],mylist]
```

Output:

```
mylist = [['apple', 'banana'], ['red','yellow'],['item1','item2']]
```